# How to create a file of X bytes that will not compress with zip

Tags: files, zip

I am load testing an application that is essentially an upload/download request/reply.  Upload a file, zip the file, send the zipped file somewhere.  I want to load test it by sending files of X bytes to see where my limitations are.  I'm creating files of the byte size I want, but due to the nature of zip, there's really no telling what that file size will be when it's zipped up and sent back down.  So I'm sending a 400M file up, it's getting zipped down to, say, 170M and getting sent back.  This doesn't really test the mechanism as I want it to.  I want to be able to send up a 400M, let the zip happen, but still have 400M that gets sent down....

Basically, how can I create a data file, that cannot be zipped?

Comment: For testing, run the `zip` step, and then just send the original file back.

Answer (score 1):

```bsh
dd if=/dev/urandom of=file bs=1M count=400
```

Will produce a file `file` which zip will not be able to compress at all. Zip will also not be able to compress previously compressed data, including video files.

Comment: +1 I was going to say something similar: "Zip will also not be able to compress previously compressed data" — including (already) zip'ed files :-)  But I like the idea of using video files, etc., over pre-zip'ing zip files for testing, since that's a better "real world" scenario.

Comment: Thank you, that did it

Answer (score 0):

You can use a previously compressed or random file (but there is no guaranty
It won't compress, especially if the files is small), but the most straightforward method is to use the `-Z store` option of the zip command which will simply store the files to the archive without compression (assuming you use the zip(1) command).